# Route port 80 to port 5000 with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I am running a tornado server on a Raspberry Pi running Archlinux. In order to avoid running the process as root I would like to run the server at port 5000 while routing all TCP packets coming in on port 80 to port 5000, and vice versa.

I have looked into iptables, but I cannot wrap my head around the configuration syntax. The examples I could find on Google are not especially transparent. Could anyone be kind enough to provide me with the commands necessary to accomplish this? Bonus points for explaining the different parts of the commands.

Comment: Port redirection is more of a sys-admin/super-user question than a programming problem

Comment: Good question, but really it is for superuser. I am voting to redirect  it there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install a 'prerouting/nat' style rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5000
```

The instructions are:

1. `-t nat` - this affects the nat table
2. `-A PREROUTING` - append to PREROUTING chain - this is pretty much the 'as soon as I see this packet' chain
3. `-i eth0` - this is the interface that is affected
4. `-p tcp` - only tcp connections (e.g. http)
5. `--dport 80` - destination port 80
6. `-j REDIRECT` - when this rule matches jump to the REDIRECT chain
7. `--to-port 5000` - where this rule takes effect, redirecting to port 5000

Comment: Awesome! Probably dumb follow-up question: does this also route the HTTP responses correctly back to the originator? I.e., I don't need a separate rule for the responses?

Comment: Yes, it routes the responses back.

Comment: Does the changes remain permanent or should be done after each reboot?

Comment: The change is lost if the system reboots. There are several mechanisms for making the setting permanent, such as the iptables-persistent software package.